# How do i replace ' ', string after each 4 characters of my text line

Tags: php, string

I we like to replace ' ', string after each 4 characters of my text characters line

I have:

```
  $str ="nameoboyfinegood";
```

I want the string

> nameoboyfinegood

to become

> 'name','oboy','fine','good'
>   all help appreciated

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Check out [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function.

Comment: should each word be enclosed in single quotes explicitly? Do you want this result `"'name','oboy','fine','good'"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string is strictly ASCII you can do the naive thing:

```
$str ="nameoboyfinegood"; 
$chunks = str_split($str,4);
print_r($chunks);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => oboy
    [2] => fine
    [3] => good
)
```

Of course this does not work for Unicode strings because [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) will break apart mutlibyte characters.

Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/45295d0e0918dcc0b9551d2146c3850987abe200

Answer (score 3):

### Use [str_split](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_split.asp) in PHP

**Syntax :-** `str_split(string,length)`

```
$str = "nameoboyfinegood";
echo implode(",", str_split($str, 4));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code to get an array contains all parts of the string:

```
<?php

preg_match_all('/(.{4})/', 'nameoboyfinegood', $matches);
```

And then you can use implode function to continate all parts to one string:

```
echo "'". implode("','", $matches[1]) . "'";
```

Result:

```
'name','oboy','fine','good'
```

Comment: I like this solution. It allows you the option of putting the `/u` modifier in the regex and make it presumably work for Unicode as well

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$array = str_split($str, 4);

echo implode(",",$array);
```